# It is very difficult to iron the clothes

Tags: clothing

It is very difficult to iron my clothes. This is my iron.

Whenever I use the iron, the cloth sticks to it, what should I do?

[image: image of the iron box]

Comment: What is the substance stuck to the sole plate of your iron? Is is melted-on cloth or damaged non-stick layer or something else?

Comment: Get a new iron, and turn down the temperature, you're melting your clothes onto the iron and that's why it's difficult.

Answer (score 9):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but with what an electric iron costs these days, the first thing to try is buying another one and not abusing it in the way this one has apparently been abused.

I see some foreign material (melted synthetic fabric?) stuck on the sole plate, and further, about half of the steam vents are clogged with something (can't be sure from the photo whether it's scale from hard water, or more of whatever is stuck on the plate).

Either way, there's also apparently damage to the non-stick coating around the steam vents, and there will almost certainly be more before you can remove the stuck-on material -- and then the steam system still won't work as it should.

A new iron costs (last I checked, in the USA) around $20 for a full-feature steam type -- if your time is worth anything, you'd be far ahead to just buy one and throw that one into the trash or recycling.

Comment: Correction: “A new iron costs ... around $20 _in the US_”. Cost etc. in other countries may of course vary!

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna start by telling you **a way to clean this**. Plug in the iron and **rub a paracetamol tablet** on its ironing surface whilst it is hot. This would melt the sticky substance altogether and you could now wipe it off with a tissue or something. This always works for me but please be careful!!

Concerning **how to prevent this** in the first place, I think the heat for whatever fabric type should always be set to the appropriate mark. Every type of fabric has the **appropriate temperature** it should be set to so check your iron. This prevents burning. If you feel the iron is too hot also, please reduce the temperature.

Also **keep the iron standing when you are temporally not ironing** (for example when adjusting or folding your clothes). This prevents the burning of any surface it might be placed on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer! Definitely sounds like the OP is melting/burning their clothes to the iron, hopefully they have a working temperature adjustment on their iron and life goes better for them :)

Comment: Why paracetamol (acetaminophen)? Is it a solvent when liquid? Is there a reason to use it instead of acetone?

Comment: Paracetamol because I heard it worked so I tried it and fortunately, it has always worked. I have never used acetone so I can neither make a comparison nor have a preference. I rub a solid tablet of paracetamol on the stain and the stain melts for easy wiping off.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t replace it Then Clean your iron.
It has burns on the plate because you’re using it too hot and not keeping it topped up with water.
Do not use an abrasive cloth as it will scratch the plate making it is less.
Don’t use on clothes with vinyl printing or nylon which can melt.